# How to listen for mouseclick after buttonclick C#

Tags: c#, event-listener, mouseclick-event

I am fairly new to C#;

I have a button that after its been clicked has to listen for a mouse click to get the coordinates of the mouse.

```
        private void AddBuilding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddBuilding.Text = "Select coords";

            // listen for second click
            AddBuilding.Text = "Add"; //Change the button text back.

        }
```

---

Edit:

```
        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public new bool Capture { get; set; }


        private void Control_MouseDown(System.Object sender,
    System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;
            if (control.Capture)
            {
                label1.Text = control.Name + " has captured the mouse";
            }
        }
```

The Control_MouseDown isn't referenced anywhere, and I am not able to call it either

```
Control_MouseDown();
```

Because that gives an error.

Comment: The first click on the building button should put your form in "add building" mode and the second click (on your picturebox?) should paint the building there.. These are two spearate events in time, with separate handlers doing separate things, controlled by a variable both can access (one to set the variable, one to read it)

Comment: No, maybe my question was confusing. I am sorry for that. 
The first click changes the text of the button to "select coords". Then it should that check if the user has clicked (somewhere on the screen) with the mouse. and get the coordinates from that location.

Comment: Use the [Capture property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.capture?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Capture), it ensures all mouse events are captured, even if it is outside of the control or the form.  You need a *bool* variable so you'll know the next Click is supposed to be used to select a coordinate.  No guarantee you'll get it (type Ctrl+Esc to test), reset the bool and the button text with the MouseCaptureChanged event.

Comment: I do not seem to get it working... any tips?